# ¿Porque no me deja entrar django admin?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema a la hora de iniciar el admin de Django. Cuando voy a poner el usuario y contraseña (que son los correctos y con la creacion de superusuario) me dice que uno de los campos no son correctos.

¿Qué puedo hacer en este caso y poder entrar a mi django admin?

Comment: Crear un superusuario.

Comment: Ya tengo creado el super usario, el problema esta en que no me deja entrar dentro de la parte admin

Comment: Crea otro, entras al admin area, corriges la contraseña del primero. Luego entras con el primero y borras el segundo.

Comment: aunque cree otro usuario no me deja

Comment: Has revisado tu log para ver qué error te devuelve, si no te deja entrar lo más probable es que no hayas corrido las migraciones correctamente prueba eliminar todas las tablas y volver a aplicar migraciones y crear de nuevo el usuario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente te falte hacer el `python manage.py migrate` para crear las tablas en la base de datos correspondientes a los **usuarios** y **permisos**.